# Delay on change image source

Tags: javascript, performance

i've written this Java Script function to change an image source:

```
function showPicture(obj) {
    var itemId = getRandomArbitrary(0, 6);
    obj.src = list[itemId].src;
    obj.dataset.start = Date.now();
    obj.dataset.id = list[itemId].id;
    obj.style.display = "block";
}
```

I think there is a delay, depending on the image size, between showPicture() and the Picture is realy shown in the browser. How can i measure it? Or is there an event like OnImageFinishedRendered?

**The images are preloaded and served from the browser cache.**

Comment: `imgObj.onload` can be used..

Comment: May be [this](https://jsfiddle.net/t4j422fw/) is what you are asking..

Comment: I think the *real* delay is higher...
try #1 delay 0[ms]
try #2 delay 37[ms]
try #3 delay 0[ms]
try #4 delay 12[ms]
try #5 delay 5[ms]

Comment: It depends..You can't really estimate it..And `onload` seems the only option to me...

Comment: `$("#img-1").click(function () {
            console.log(Date.now() - this.dataset.start);
        });`

If I see the picture i click on it. My reaction time moves between 300 [ms] and 3000 [ms]. In my opinion there is a (technical) delay, but how can i figure it out?

Comment: To get a better and accurate answer, always provide complete question. Your question and scenarios you are asking seems incomplete to me...

Comment: Sure there is a lot more code... But the question is complete: "How can I measure the delay between `function ShowPicture()` and the image presentation on the screen?"

Comment: Your sentence is complete but not the question. Where is `img-1` element in your question? Where is click handler ? How function `showPicture` is being called ? What is `obj` ? What is `list` ? If the images are preloaded then logically there should not be any delay(Except the time taken by browser to draw the image). Hence _question is incomplete_